# M2.2.4 Checkout: Adding New Shipping Address automatically sets address as Billing Address

Tags: onepage-checkout, shipping-address, magento2.2.4, billing-address

When adding a new address to the shipping address list on the first part of the onepage checkout, I have noticed that it will automatically set the new shipping address as the billing address on the payment step.

This is not what I am looking for as it is intended for B2B and needs to maintain the same set billing address at all times, regardless of added shipping addresses. So even removing the billing address altogether from the checkout would be sufficient.

Any ideas?

If you pick an already set address, go the the next step, the billing is fine, and then going back and adding a new one, the billing is still fine. This issue only occurs when first initially loading the checkout page, immediately creating a new address and then moving onto the payment page, the billing is now changed to the newly created shipping address.

Would anyone know where or why this new address is being called from?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I found the location of the New Address form, however it doesn't seem to have any indication anywhere that would make it end up being forced as the billing address.

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/form.html
```

Also saw this post: [Magento 2 : Default billing address not selected by default on checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139195/magento-2-default-billing-address-not-selected-by-default-on-checkout-page)

Tried their method as well, to no avail.

**EDIT 2:**

I have found that

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js
```

appears to be where all the inner workings are, however I'm not sure what to change to essentially force the checkout to always use the default billing address of the account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a hefty amount of searching, I was able to find the issue posted on github along with some community members resolutions that worked just fine.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8777#issuecomment-359847592

The small extension by ClassyLlama works as intended, maintaining the default billing no matter what you try to play with and change on the shipping steps.